# Is it true that every star of a dominating set of a graph $H$ is a clique in $H^2$?

Tags: graph-theory

Let $D$ be a minimum dominating set in $H$. Then $H$ contains $|D|$ stars spanning all vertices. I would like to know:

1. Is it true that each of these stars will be clique in $H^2$? and Why?
2. If the above question is yes, then $H^2$ contains $|D|$ cliques, will these cliques spanning all the vertices?

$H^2$ is [graph power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_power) of $H$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know what H^2 means?

Comment: @heynongman it is graph power https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_power

Comment: I know. But which edges are added in H^2? When do I put an edge between two vertices x and y?

Comment: Every vertices which its distance in $H$ is $\leq 2$

Comment: Right. So in a star, what is the maximum distance between any two vertices?

Comment: A star is a vertex $v$ and set of vertices that are adjacent to $v$. so  it is $1$

Comment: @heynongman look at this book, https://books.google.com/books?id=EILqAmzKgYIC&pg=PA47&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q&f=false go to the next page (page 48 of the book) . Lemma 5.2

Comment: Take two leaves from the star. They are at a distance of 2 in the star. So in H^2 we would draw an edge between them.

Comment: Yes you are right. So in every star, all vertices are connect. I can't believe I missed this. Thanks